# Angular (8/9) i18n expecting to see a translation with a specific numeric id in error

Tags: angular, localization

Several months ago I had a select ICU expression in my application that looked something like this:

.xlf (translation) file:

```html
<trans-unit id="my-custom-id">
  <source>{ VAR_SELECT, select, A {text for option A} B {text for option B} }</ source>
  <target>{ VAR_SELECT, select, A {text for option A} B {text for option B} }</ target>
</trans-unit>
```

But in my i18n attribute in the html, I had forgotten to prefix the id with @@, meaning it wasn't treated as an Id and Angular (8 at the time) assigned its own numeric Id and threw an error during the build process complaining that a translation was missing for that Id.

"No translation found for "8718798238785245459" ("{VAR_SELECT, select, A {text for option A} B {text for option B} }"

Note the VAR_SELECT text as this variable name was changed at the time this correction was made.

The error stopped appearing when I added the @@ characters to the i18n attribute.  I haven't seen it in months, until recently when it reappeared.

Two recent significant changes were made:

1. We upgraded to Angular 9 - may or may not be relevant
2. I added a new select ICU expression for an error message, which was basically the same as the previous one except for being suffixed with the text "is a required field" and of course has its own unique id:

```html
<trans-unit id="my-required-error-message-custom-id">
  <source>{ NewVariableName, select, A {text for option A} B {text for option B} } is a required field</ source>
  <target>{ NewVariableName, select, A {text for option A} B {text for option B} } is a required field</ target>
</trans-unit>
```

This all works as intended, but if I build using build-ci-pr, the original error I had several months ago returns, complete with the reference to the old variable name VAR_SELECT.

If I remove the html element I added to consume this translation, this error goes away.  If I add it back in, it returns.  It has the correct id.  It is prefixed with @@.

The most telling part of this is that the error message includes "VAR_SELECT".  There isn't any translation in our system that uses this any more.

So Angular clearly stores values for translations it expects to see and it has this one in error.  However this is stored, it isn't searchable, because searching for this id turns up nothing.  How do I stop angular from expecting a translation with this id to be present?

Update: Still no idea what was causing this, but we were having such problems with ICU expressions after the Angular 9 upgrade that we decided to remove them all and use $localize instead.  Angular 9 translations appear to be extremely buggy.

Comment: How is your ICU select expression receiving its value?  If it's via an input then you're having the same issue as we are for which I opened an issue with the angular team here. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36725

Comment: It's a custom control value accessor component that acts like a dropdown.  But it doesn't actually include any input tags.